# jQuery delegate is not working?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use delegate to call a function, when a specific set of links get click.
I have already used it before in some other page. It was worked there. But, this time i even not able to find, where the problem is.

My links were dynamically generated, they looks like

```
<a class="thumbLink" href="#" id="My HomeTown-1"><small>My HomeTown</small></a>
```

And the jQuery delegate function is,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#albumHolder").delegate('a.thumbLink', 'click', this.loadAlbum);//albumHolder is div ID that holds all the <a> elements

this.loadAlbum = function(){
    var id = this.id;
    var number = id.lastIndexOf("-");
    var alubmName = id.subString(0, number);
    alert(albumName);
}
});
```

**Update:**

I tried both versions, But i am not able to make it work!

```
$("#albumHolder").delegate('a.thumbLink', 'click', function loadAlbum(){
    var id = this.id;
    var number = id.lastIndexOf("-");
    var alubmName = id.subString(0, number);
    alert(albumName);
});



   this.loadAlbum(){
    var id = this.id;
    var number = id.lastIndexOf("-");
    var alubmName = id.subString(0, number);
    alert(albumName);
}
$("#albumHolder").delegate('a.thumbLink', 'click', this.loadAlbum);
```

The above code is in `$(document).ready(function(){});`. Is that correct??
i also tried by putting them in a separate `js` file. I cannot make it work.

Any idea about my problem!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that's the order of your actual code, you're trying to pass the function expression before it has been initialized.

Reverse them and it should work:

```
this.loadAlbum = function(){
    var id = this.id;
    var number = id.lastIndexOf("-");
    var alubmName = id.subString(0, number);
    alert(albumName);
}
$("#albumHolder").delegate('a.thumbLink', 'click', this.loadAlbum);
```

Comment: #@patrick dw: Its not working. I also tired to use `.live()`. Its also not working. Does it make any sense to you!!! Anyway i have updated my question with the `try` results.

Comment: @CS 1.6 - Is the `#albumHolder` element dynamically created as well? Also, is there any chance you're using an older version of jQuery on this project?

Comment: @CS 1.6 - Ok, yeah, you'll either need to manually assign the `delegate()` handler to it when it is created, or use `.live()` instead of `.delegate()`. (I'd suggest sticking with `.delegate()`.)

Comment: @patrick dw: is it rule to use its direct parent id!!! or shall i use any other #id, for example shall i use `a` for this html  `<div id="a"><div id="b"><a class="href"></a></div></div>`

Comment: @CS 1.6: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. If you mean when using `.delegate()`, you can specify any ancestor of the element you're targeting. It doesn't need to be the direct parent. EDIT: Glad you've got it working. :o)

Comment: @patrick dw: Thanks for the hint `any ancestor of the element you're targeting`!!!

Answer (score 4):

You use a function expression before defining it. This doesn't work. Either use a regular function declaration (`function loadAlbum() { /* ... */ }`) or define `this.loadAlbum` (`this.loadAlbum = function() { /* ... */ }`) before using it in your delegate() call.

Comment: I tried it. Its not working for me. I have updated the question with the results.